# pandas merge two dataframes without cross-references and with NaN's for uneven number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

**EDITED 3/5/19:**

Tried different ways to merge and/or join the data below but couldn't wrap my head around how to do that correctly.

Initially I have a data like this:

```
index  unique_id  group_name  id  name
0      100        ABC         20  aaa
1      100        ABC         21  bbb
2      100        DEF         22  ccc
3      100        DEF         23  ddd
4      100        DEF         24  eee
5      100        DEF         25  fff
6      101        ABC         30  ggg
7      101        ABC         31  hhh
8      101        ABC         32  iii
9      101        DEF         33  jjj
```

The goal is to reshape it by merging on `unique_id` so that the result looks like this:

```
index  unique_id  group_name_x  id_x   name_x  group_name_y  id_y  name_y
0      100        ABC           20     aaa     DEF           22    ccc
1      100        ABC           21     bbb     DEF           23    ddd
2      100        NaN           NaN    NaN     DEF           24    eee
3      100        NaN           NaN    NaN     DEF           25    fff
4      101        ABC           30     ggg     DEF           33    jjj
5      101        ABC           31     hhh     NaN           NaN   NaN
6      101        ABC           32     iii     NaN           NaN   NaN
```

How can I do this in pandas? The best I could think of is to split the data into two dataframes by group name (ABC and DEF) and then merge them with `how='outer', on='unique_id'`, but that way it creates references between each record (2 ABC x 4 DEF = 8 records) without any NaN's.

`pd.concat` with `axis=1` mentioned in answers doesn't align the data per `unique_id` and doesn't create any NaN's.

Answer (score 0):

As you said , split the dataframe then `concat` both dataframe by row wise after resetting both index

A working code,

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
req_cols=['group_name','id','name']
df_1=df[df['group_name']=='ABC'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_2=df[df['group_name']=='DEF'].reset_index(drop=True)
df_1=df_1.rename(columns = dict(zip(df_1[req_cols].columns.values, df_1[req_cols].add_suffix('_x'))))
df_2=df_2.rename(columns = dict(zip(df_2[req_cols].columns.values, df_2[req_cols].add_suffix('_y'))))
req_cols_x=[val+'_x'for val in req_cols]
print (pd.concat([df_2,df_1[req_cols_x]],axis=1))
```

O/P:

```
   index  unique_id group_name_y  id_y name_y group_name_x  id_x name_x
0      2        100          DEF    22    ccc          ABC  20.0    aaa
1      3        100          DEF    23    ddd          ABC  21.0    bbb
2      4        100          DEF    24    eee          NaN   NaN    NaN
3      5        100          DEF    25    fff          NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I clarified my question by editing the input and desired output, please take a look!